# Data structure for parse tree in natural language C/C++

Tags: c++, c, boost, data-structures, tree

I would like to store sentence in data structure in C/C++. Example this sentence `"This uploads files to a remote machine."` is represented as :

```
(TOP
  (S
    (NP (DT This))
    (VP
      (VBZ uploads)
      (NP (NNS files))
      (PP (TO to) (NP (DT a) (JJ remote) (NN machine))))
    (. .)))
```

like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959723/searching-natural-language-sentence-structure)
Is there a simple way to do it in C/C++? I am building manually the tree (not using parser).

Answer (score 2):

That parser mentioned at http://opennlp.apache.org/ is very complex.  It divides a sentence into nouns, verbs, prepositions, etc.  If you are attempting to re-write this in c/c++, this is a huge undertaking.

Better to use the parser and read the output into c/c++ data structures.

Assuming you have the output of the parser, the format of the output is then fairly straight forward.  The structure would be something like this:

```
struct SentencePart {
  SType type;
  // If the type is a basic word type (e.g. NN, JJ, etc)
  char* word;      
  // If the type is a complex sub-sentence.
  struct SentencePart* sentence_part;
};
```

You can create an enumeration of the types (TOP, S, VP, NP, etc).  Then you can read the input and create the structure based on the type you scan in.

This is a very simple way to do it, and there could be others.

Comment: I am not attempting to re-write the parser. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Trenin's answer, I would use a directory-style tree, where siblings are coordinate parts and children are subordinate parts:

```
typedef struct Token Token;

struct Token {
    const char *type;   /* Type of token, cold be an enum */
    const char *data;   /* associated word */
    Token *next;        /* next coordinate token */
    Token *child;       /* eldest subordinate token */
};
```

You can then devise a level-based approach to insert your tokens into that tree:

```
root = token_new_level(0, "TOP", NULL);

token_new_level(1,          "S", NULL);
token_new_level(  2,        "NP", NULL);
token_new_level(    3,      "DT", "this");
token_new_level(  2,        "VP", NULL);
token_new_level(    3,      "VPZ", "uploads");
token_new_level(    3,      "NP", NULL);
token_new_level(      4,    "NNS", "files");
token_new_level(    3,      "PP", NULL);
token_new_level(      4,    "TO", "to");
token_new_level(      4,    "NP", NULL);
token_new_level(        5,  "DT", "a");
token_new_level(        5,  "JJ", "remote");
token_new_level(        5,  "NN", "machine");
token_new_level(  2,        ".", ".");
```

which yields:

```
OP
    S
        NP
            DT this
        VP
            VPZ uploads
            NP
                NNS files
            PP
                TO to
                NP
                    DT a
                    JJ remote
                    NN machine
        . .
```

as tree or in flat representation:

```
 (TOP (S (NP (DT this)) (VP (VPZ uploads) (NP (NNS files)) 
      (PP (TO to) (NP (DT a) (JJ remote) (NN machine)))) (. .)))
```

The noun phrase `NP` and verb phrase `VP` are coordinate and linked via `next`. The noun phrase `NP`  and the verb phrase `VP` is subordinate to the sentence `S`, but only `NP` is stored as direct `child` of `S`.

Only tokens without children have words attached, so you could use a union in C or two different classes in C++, `Phrase` and `Word` for example, that both inherit from `Token` to refine the model.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically using S-expressions. **Edit** I missed part of the question, apparently. However, the below techniques are easily extended to other kinds of trees.

I have a fondness of using recursive Boost variants to handle these:

```
using s_expr = boost::make_recursive_variant<std::string, std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_> >::type;
using s_list = std::vector<s_expr>;
```

Of course, part of that may be because I have used Boost Spirit to trivially parse ASTs like these. So, here's my demo program showing how it's used.

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0a6cd1b29a3c47f)**

The test program shows both how to parse the sample you showed **as well as** how to construct the equivalent AST in code. Note that the assert proves that both result in the exact same expression tree:

```
int main()
{
    s_expr parsed = parse_s_expr(
            "(TOP\n"
            "  (S\n"
            "    (NP (DT This))\n"
            "    (VP\n"
            "      (VBZ uploads)\n"
            "      (NP (NNS files))\n"
            "      (PP (TO to) (NP (DT a) (JJ remote) (NN machine))))\n"
            "    (. .)"
            ")"
            ")");

    std::cout << "parsed: " << parsed           << "\n";

    // conversely, just build one:
    const s_expr in_code(s_list { 
        "TOP",
        s_list { "S",
            s_list { "NP", s_list { "DT", "This", } },
            s_list { "VP",
                s_list { "VBZ", "uploads" },
                    s_list { "NP", s_list { "NNS", "files" } },
                    s_list { "PP", s_list { "TO", "to" }, s_list { "NP", s_list { "DT", "a" }, s_list { "JJ", "remote" }, s_list { "NN", "machine" } } } },
                s_list { ".", "." }
        }
    });

    // both AST trees are exactly equivalent:
    assert(in_code == parsed);
}
```

The output (as seen on [the coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0a6cd1b29a3c47f)) is:

> `parsed: ( TOP ( S ( NP ( DT This ) ) ( VP ( VBZ uploads ) ( NP ( NNS files ) ) ( PP ( TO to ) ( NP ( DT a ) ( JJ remote ) ( NN machine ) ) ) ) ( . . ) ) )`

Here's the full program. Note that implementing the parser took all of 35 lines :) And it's pretty flexible and efficient, thanks to Spirit)

#### Full Demo Program

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx   = boost::phoenix;

using s_expr = boost::make_recursive_variant<std::string, std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_> >::type;
using s_list = std::vector<s_expr>;

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<It, s_expr(), Skipper>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(expr)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        value = lexeme [ +(graph - '(' - ')') ];
        list  = '(' >> *expr >> ')';
        expr  = list | value;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((expr)(value)(list));
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, s_expr(),      Skipper> expr;
    qi::rule<It, std::string(), Skipper> value;
    qi::rule<It, s_list(),      Skipper> list;
};

s_expr parse_s_expr(const std::string& input)
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

    static const parser<It, qi::space_type> p;

    It f(begin(input)), l(end(input));
    s_expr data;

    if (!qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,qi::space,data))
        throw std::runtime_error("parse failed: '" + std::string(f,l) + "'");

    return data;
}

namespace std { // a hack for easy debug printing
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, s_list const& l) {
        os << "( "; std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), std::ostream_iterator<s_expr>(os, " "));
        return os << ")";
    }
}

int main()
{
    s_expr parsed = parse_s_expr(
            "(TOP\n"
            "  (S\n"
            "    (NP (DT This))\n"
            "    (VP\n"
            "      (VBZ uploads)\n"
            "      (NP (NNS files))\n"
            "      (PP (TO to) (NP (DT a) (JJ remote) (NN machine))))\n"
            "    (. .)"
            ")"
            ")");

    std::cout << "parsed: " << parsed           << "\n";

    // conversely, just build one:
    const s_expr in_code(s_list { 
        "TOP",
        s_list { "S",
            s_list { "NP", s_list { "DT", "This", } },
            s_list { "VP",
                s_list { "VBZ", "uploads" },
                    s_list { "NP", s_list { "NNS", "files" } },
                    s_list { "PP", s_list { "TO", "to" }, s_list { "NP", s_list { "DT", "a" }, s_list { "JJ", "remote" }, s_list { "NN", "machine" } } } },
                s_list { ".", "." }
        }
    });

    // both AST trees are exactly equivalent:
    assert(in_code == parsed);
}
```

Comment: On re-reading the question, I appear to have missed a rather large point about `S`, `NP`, `VP` etc. being node kinds. I hope you still find my answer inspirational